# Two HTML elements displayed side by side but with in line word wrap

Tags: html, css, layout

Firstly, sorry about the question title, it may not be very descriptive for my actually requirements (which is one reason why I can't find a solution to this with a Google search - I don't know what to search for)

I am trying to layout some "label text" next to some "value text" but want to keep the value text in line even when it needs to span multiple lines.

Here is an example of the desired result...

```
Label 1        Value 1
Label 2        Value 2
Label 3        Value 3 is much longer
               so it needs to span multiple lines
               but should be keep in a nice format
Label 4        Value 4
```

I know I could easily do this with a table but I don't think a table is appropriate here. Despite what the example data might look like it is not related. Real label examples might be Name, Date, Description, and Reference Number.

I also want to try and avoid using any floating techniques if at all possible - basically because I think using a float would required me to specify a fixed width to ensure a relatively small margin between labels and values.

Other than that I am open to use any elements offered - and of course will use float/tables if they prove to be the best course of action.

[Here is a starting JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGVE5/) of it not working if anybody wants to have a quick play.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="Header">Label 1</span>
    <span class="Text">Value 1</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="Header">Label 2</span>
    <span class="Text">Value 2</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="Header">Label 3</span>
    <span class="Text">Value 3 is much longer so it needs to span multiple lines but should be keep in a nice format</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="Header">Label 4</span>
    <span class="Text">Value 4</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px; /* just for demo */
}

.Header
{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    color: #00F;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.Text
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/SGVE5/6/

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I see the overflow part is important here - I wouldn't have thought to use that for something like this though

Comment: @musefan The trick is in creating a *[block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/block_formatting_context)*

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks like tabular data if anything is. So using a simple table is the most logical, the most robust, and most flexible way:

```
<table>
<tr valign=top><td>label1 <td>value1
...
</table>
```

This way, you don’t need to be an arbitrary guess on the width of the labels, and changes in font size or text lengths do not play havoc with the page layout. Table formatting automatically allocates as much as needed. And if you need to or wish to, you can set a maximum width, or even a fixed width, for the table as a whole.